# Convert Script# Library to an Import reference assembly

Tags: script#

Is there an easy way of converting a normal Script# library into an import library for use with other projects?
I currently have to keep my 2 projects in sync - and there must be an easier way!

So just to be clear - I have a project that is compiled to js with Script#. This js library is then used as a reference library for another script# project - and so I have an import assembly that 'shadows' the library project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an import library.

If ProjectB refers to ProjectA, just reference the dll produced from ProjectA in ProjectB (as you would in a c# world). If they're in the same solution, just use a regular project-to-project reference.